# Shouldn't css3 transitions animate between height: 100% and height: 200px?

Tags: animation, css, height, interpolation, transition

css3 transitions will interpolate the state of the height of a div.

Currently, chrome13 will not interpolate if you set the height with a different unit than the previous height

i.e.:

  set height to 100%

  set height to 50% (on a different rendering frame)

  height will animate correctly (assuming proper use of transition)

  set height to 100px

  height will not animate

Chrome bug? spec bug?

Illustrative jsfiddle for the motivated: http://jsfiddle.net/zDywJ/21/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bug in Chrome or in the spec.

As far as I can see, CSS has no way to change a percentage into a pixel unit... so it would not have a way to compare the beginning and end in order to execute the transition.

Comment: That's circular reasoning - "css can't do it because css can't do it." There is a runtime component of css that can certainly figure out how many pixels 100% evaluates to. This information is already known to the runtime at the point the style is changed in my above example. The current design is severely limited in expressiveness because of this flaw.